# Extend ListViewGroupsCollection from ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

How to possible extend class ListViewGroupCollection from ListView for add the button multiple per groups?
I need to know to be able to add a button to the right of the group name.

Example one button:

- Add one button for remove groups from list.

I kept searching on google and came to the opinion that I need to expand ListViewGroup, but how to possible extend this class?

[image: ListView]

Comment: Do you mean a button to collapse/expand the groups? If so, read [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31276/Add-Group-Collapse-Behavior-on-a-Listview-Control) and [this](http://johnatten.com/2012/05/09/extending-c-listview-with-collapsible-groups-part-i/)

Comment: I'm sorry. This is not for help. I edited the post with new information.